# How to say "engineering the future" in Latin to use as a motto?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I've checked with Google Translate, but fiddling around with words versus phrases is confusing me because it doesn't seem like this can just be a direct translation.

Alternatively, how would you say "building the future" or "creating the future"? Looking for a motto that conveys that we're shaping (innovating) the future in our space.

Comment: related and worth considering: *Faber est quisque fortunae suae.* (Every man is the maker of his own fortune.)

Answer (score 1):

"We build the future" would be *futurum condimus,* or possibly even better *futurum facimus.* The latter also gets you alliteration, if you're looking for a motto.

Comment: Nonne *futura* aptius videtur? (Quamquam conicio si *futurum* dicis, *tempus* esse subaudiendum, sed res, non tempus condimus.)